# Конвертировать массив в HashMap

Tags: java, массивы, java-hashmap

Как конвертировать

```
int[] hotbar
```

в

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer>
```

?

Comment: Желательно указывать, что у вас должно быть ключом, а что значением. А то может у вас ключ и значения должны совпадать, а может четные элементы должны стать ключами, нечетными значениями. Нужно в вопросе прописывать всю необходимую информацию, чтобы отвечающим не нужно было догадываться, что конкретно вы хотели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант со стримом:

```
Arrays.stream(hotbar)
    .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Function.identity())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное сейчас начнут стримы всякие предлагать и модерновые операции. Но в целом можно обойтись простым циклом.

```
int [] array = {3, 1, 4, 6, 5};
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
 
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
   map.put(i, array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```java
int[] arr = {11, 22, 33, 44};

HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int el : arr) map.compute(el, (key, value) -> key);

System.out.println(map); // {11=11, 22=22, 33=33, 44=44}
```